# creating table syntax error

Tags: mysql

I have a problem creating the table. It says unexpected parenthesis at line 3

```
CREATE DATABASE scl_teachers;

USE scl_teachers;

CREATE TABLE clteacher (
    'id' INT (10) PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
    'f_name' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    'mid_initials' (255) IS NULL,
    'l_name' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    'saturation' VARCHAR(2)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't use single quotes **`'`** to quote identifiers in MySQL.  You use a backtick **`` ` ``** or you can use nothing at all, if the identifier isn't a reserved word.

```
'mid_initials' (255) IS NULL,
```

Should be

```
`mid_initials` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
```

...although using a `VARCHAR(255)` seems unnecessarily large.

Comment: solved!! Thnaks

Answer (score 1):

The datatype `int` doesn't accept a data length.  `int` is just `int`.

So, this should get you going:

```
CREATE TABLE clteacher (
    `id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    ,f_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    ,mid_initials VARCHAR(255) NULL
    ,l_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    ,saturation VARCHAR(2)
    );
```

Comment: removed the length. still same error.

Comment: What you're looking for is called `IDENTITY'.  You feed it a start (seed) value, then how much to increment by.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: the error code is syntax error: unexpected '(' (opening parenthesis)

Comment: Forgot, it's mysql.  Updating answer

Comment: doesn't help. still the same. I am working in mysql workbench 6.2.

Comment: Same exact error?